# Jquery dom manipulation with knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I would like to create a expandable/collapsable div based on content inside the div. Basically if the div's height is > 50px i would like to add a link to expand the div to read the content and then collapse it.

I have a div that is bound using Knockout. I tried the following options and it didnt work:

1. Used the jquery script in document.ready, it is not able to find the elements
2. Used custom KO bindings with init and update. This does not work because my div's height comes back as 0 all the time.

What is the best way to manipulate the final HTML after KO has completed its bindings.

Please advise

Here is my html

```
<div data-bind="foreach: notes" class="coment_div">
    <div class="mycontainer" data-bind="collapseUI:true">
        <p class="date_custome" data-bind="text:formattedDate"></p>
        <p class="comment">
            <span data-bind="text:comment"></span>
        </p>
        <p class="read-more"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jquery script

```
var slideHeight = 50;
$(".myContainer").each(function() {
    var $this = $(element);
    var $wrap = $this.children(".comment");
    var defHeight = $wrap.height();
    if (defHeight >= slideHeight) {
        var $readMore = $this.find(".read-more");
        $wrap.css("height", slideHeight + "px");
        $readMore.append("<a href='#'>Read More...</a>");
        $readMore.children("a").bind("click", function(event) {
            var curHeight = $wrap.height();
            if (curHeight == slideHeight) {
                $wrap.animate({
                    height: defHeight
                }, "normal");
                $(this).text("Collapse");
                $wrap.children(".gradient").fadeOut();
            } else {
                $wrap.animate({
                    height: slideHeight
                }, "normal");
                $(this).text("Read More...");
                $wrap.children(".gradient").fadeIn();
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on the **afterRender/afterAdd** options in the **[documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-7-post-processing-or-animating-the-generated-dom-elements)**.

Basically, it would look something like this (based on your code)

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: notes, afterRender: addReadMoreWidget }" 
     class="coment_div">
    ...
</div>
```

The `addReadMoreWidget` function will be called after the section is rendered.  The documentation page I linked to above details the arguments passed to the `afterRender` function.

Hope that's of use to you.

Comment: Knockout is one of those libraries that comes standard with "but wait, there's more!" built-in. :-)

Comment: This creates dependency to the DOM from the viewmodel, so I think it should not be used. Better to create a custom binding or other abstraction away from DOM